# Any Monero projects in Python?

Tags: development, python

I'm curious if there are any interesting projects in Python for Monero. I have to write some big long explanation here so I can post this simple question. Good job SE!

Comment: Mr Schdn, I think you may have rushed here. The number of Python projects is 3 (as the answer to my question states in TWO lines of text). How is that "too broad" or "too many possible answers" or "answers would be too long"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

there is [MiniNero](https://github.com/monero-project/mininero) and [RingCT-Python](https://github.com/ShenNoether/RingCT-Python) as simple implementations of the the math behind Monero

there is also the GUI lightwallet which is implemented in python.

Comment: there is also a RPC client implementation called [PyMonero](https://github.com/Monero-Monitor/pymonero)

Comment: Those projects look very interesting but do you know what they mean by "reimplementation"? Is that the C++ code redone in Python?

Comment: is basically, as i understand, the other way around. aka they implement any changes how the generate a transaction and there keyimage in python to look if it works and if they are happy with it they implement it in C++